# text class style not changing of custom style

Tags: flutter, text, styles

i have on custom Text class and
one custom Textstyle.

When i change custom texstyle color but
color is not changed.
i want result aaaaa  in red color
and           bbbbb  in black color

Code is attached

Thanks in advance

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            MyCustomText(text: "aaaaa", style: CtrBlblStyle()),
            MyCustomText(
                text: "bbbbb", style: CtrBlblStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CtrPublic {
  static const Color textColor = Colors.red;
}

class CtrBlblStyle extends TextStyle {
  final Color color;
  CtrBlblStyle({
    this.color = CtrPublic.textColor,
  });
}

class MyCustomText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextStyle style;
  MyCustomText({
    this.text,
    this.style,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      text,
      style: CtrBlblStyle(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `MyCustomText` to avoid creating a new `CtrlBlblStyle` instance.

You are passing the different `CtrlBlblStyle` instances, created with different `TextStyles` values, to `MyCustomText` but not using them inside the class, instead you are creating a new `CtrlBlblStyle` instance, that defaults to red because it receives no constructor parameters, change this line:

```dart
style: CtrBlblStyle(),
```

For this:

```dart
style: style,
```

The class:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            MyCustomText(text: "aaaaa", style: CtrBlblStyle()),
            MyCustomText(
                text: "bbbbb", style: CtrBlblStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CtrPublic {
  static const Color textColor = Colors.red;
}

class CtrBlblStyle extends TextStyle {
  final Color color;
  CtrBlblStyle({
    this.color = CtrPublic.textColor,
  });
}

class MyCustomText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextStyle style;
  MyCustomText({
    this.text,
    this.style,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      text,

      // Update this line
      style: style,

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying , But my question is slightly wrong , Apologies .         MyCustomText(text: "aaaaa", style: CtrBlblStyle())               this line  needed to be    MyCustomText(text: "aaaaa")    because MyCustomText should get color inherited from CtrPublic , the line you changed

Comment: If you found this answer useful and want to say thanks, do it by [marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and/or voting on it. See in the help pages why [voting is important](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it this way. No need to go such a roundabout way for this.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            MyCustomText(text: "aaaaa"),
            MyCustomText(
                text: "bbbbb", style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextStyle style;
  MyCustomText({
    this.text,
    this.style
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      text,
      style: style??TextStyle(color:Colors.red),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sir , Problem solved . But I am still not getting why my class didn't work. Technically , it should have changed properties from CtrBlblStyle() class .

Comment: Like the answer below says, you are passing `CtrBlblStyle()` on style of `MyCustomText` widget. So, no matter what you pass when you call `MyCustomText` the style is already `CtrlBlblStyle()` because you are not using what you pass as a style. For that you would need to pass `style:style` on `MyCustomText` and only then you will be able to reflect the new value you passed while using the widget. I would recommend my way because it is a lot lesser code and neater as  well.